# Does the heal skill depend on your level or the patient's?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

It says "2 hit points per level for a full 8 hours of rest in a day."

Is that the patient's character level or the healer's character level?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The context of [the Heal skill](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/heal) makes this clear:

> If your Heal check is successful, **the patient recovers** hit points or ability score points (lost to ability damage) **at twice the normal rate**: 2 hit points per level for a full 8 hours of rest in a day, or 4 hit points per level for each full day of complete rest; 2 ability score points for a full 8 hours of rest in a day, or 4 ability score points for each full day of complete rest.

It is the subject's level, as the skill clarifies it's "twice the normal rate."

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the patient's, being an improvement over what he'd normally heal if he was just resting without a nearby healer doing his "magic".